# git merge of identical changes -> make git blame target the merged commit

Tags: git

Assuming the following constellation:

```
A   a - b - c
     \       \
B     d - e - f
```

There is an identical change to a file in commits `b` and `d`.
Now the user calls `git blame` at `f` (after the merge of `A` into `B`) and looks at this change.

**What I want to achieve that the commit `b` is blamed on the mentioned change.** Yet, regularly this change is blamed on d.

Closest I have gotten is: `git merge A -s recursive -X theirs`. This works, if there have been any other modifications to the file, e.g. during `c`. But it does not work, when there have been no other changes, meaning that the file is identical in `c` and `e`.

Now I understand that this is mainly due to the fact, that the file is identical in `e` and `f`, so it does not even appear in the list of changes files of commit `f`. Still I wish to know if there is any solution/workaround that does not involve me creating a fake change (between `e` and `f`) before the merge, which is then removed during the merge.

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not *completely* sure of this, my hunch is that it depends on the order of the parents on the merge commit. git won't see if the line was present on all of its parents to then set a competition to see which one made it first. It will check (according to my hunch) parent by parent until it finds it. When it does, it will track down when the line came up in that branch. So, it's really about the order of the parents in the merge revision. Take a look at what `git commit-tree` does.

Answer (score 1):

See how your commit ids are ordered when you run `git rev-list`,

you may be able to hack something using the [`-S <revs-file>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt--Sltrevs-filegt) option, by creating a file where you would first list the revisions coming from the `b-c` branch, then from the `d-e` branch :

```sh
# in revlist.sh :
# first list the revisions coming from the merged branch :
git rev-list HEAD^..HEAD
# then the rev-list from the 'first-parent' part
git rev-list HEAD^

# in git blame :
git blame -S <(revlist.sh)
```

Answer (score 1):

`git log --oneline --left-only --cherry-mark f^1...f^2` will mark all cherry-picks in the mainline, you can feed those to blame's `--ignore-revs`.

Answer (score 0):

At `f`, `d` is the commit that first made the change, not `b`. So `d` is blamed. When you blame A, then you will get `b`. The diff of `c` and `f` will not have the changes you mentioned, so `b` will more or less be ignored if `d` and `b` have an identical set of changes